# How do you add tab-focusing (key view loop) to buttons in SwiftUI for MacOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui

Adding `.focusable()` to a `Button` view seems to have no effect. The event handlers never fire either.

```
      Button(action: {}) {
        Text("one")
      }
      .focusable(true) { _ in
        print("focused one") // never fires
      }

      Button(action: {}) {
        Text("two")
      }
      .focusable(true) { _ in
        print("focused two") // never fires
      }
```

Is there a way to make the buttons tab-focusable?

Comment: It just works. Have you turned on "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls" in System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts?

Comment: You're right, I never realized that was necessary because some applications provide tab navigation without enabling that option.